# Setting markers in a map, without the image of a map (custom image)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm developing a map that is a radar, so it's not a map!

My idea setting markers on a invisible map, and instead of the classic map, set this image:

[image]

So, the green points would be the markers set as LAT / LON but you can't see the map, but you can see a picture.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done something like this in one of my project. i had created custom ImageView, pass lat longs and draw on the bitmap set to that ImageView.

my requirement was to draw lat long on US map.

so, you can create a custom ImageView which holds your radar image. and pass List of lat longs to that class to draw the points on the radar image.

here's my custom ImageView class.

```
    public class MapImageView extends ImageView{
    private float latitudeTop, latitudeBottom, longitudeRight, longitudeLeft;
    private List<Float> points = new ArrayList<Float>();
    private Paint pointPaint;
    private Matrix pointMatrix = new Matrix();

    public MapImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        pointPaint = new Paint();
        pointPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        pointPaint.setStrokeCap(Cap.ROUND);
        pointPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        pointPaint.setStrokeWidth(2.5f);
    }

    public void setBounds(float latitudeTop, float latitudeBottom, float longitudeLeft, float longitudeRight) {
        this.latitudeTop    = latitudeTop;
        this.latitudeBottom = latitudeBottom;
        this.longitudeLeft  = longitudeLeft;
        this.longitudeRight = longitudeRight;
    }

    public void addPoint(float latitude, float longitude) {
        points.add(longitude);
        points.add(latitude);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setPoints(List<Float> points){
        this.points = points;
        LogMsg.d("PP GOT "+this.points.size());
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);        
        LogMsg.d("Image: -latitude: "+latitudeTop+" longitude: "+longitudeLeft);
        LogMsg.d("width: "+getMeasuredWidth()/(longitudeRight-longitudeLeft)+" Height: "+getMeasuredHeight()/(latitudeBottom-latitudeTop));
        pointMatrix.reset();
        pointMatrix.postTranslate(-longitudeLeft, -latitudeTop);
        pointMatrix.postScale(getMeasuredWidth()/(longitudeRight-longitudeLeft),getMeasuredHeight()/(latitudeBottom-latitudeTop));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPoints(mapPoints(), pointPaint);
    }

    private float[] mapPoints() {
        float[] pts = new float[points.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            pts[i] = points.get(i);
        }
        pointMatrix.mapPoints(pts);
        return pts;
    }
}
```

Here's setting bound from onCreate(), setting bound is actually the lat and longs of US Map.

```
mMapAppStats.setBounds(49.066668f, 25.482951f, -124.962159f, -65.932619f);
```

Then you can add points to this imageview like this.

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < appStatsLocations.size(); i++) {
        mMapAppStats.addPoint(Float.parseFloat(appStatsLocations.get(i).getLatitude()), Float.parseFloat(appStatsLocations.get(i).getLongitude()));
    }
```

here's the XML.

```
<...MapImageView
            android:id="@+id/mapAppStats"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnAppStatsViewTeamNFriends"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/usmapnew" />
```

You can get some idea from this to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, it's what I expected. I was looking for calculating all the coordinates but I know Android devices are pretty different between each other and that would be crazy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Maps for that.

1. Implement the Google Maps SDK
2. Make a custom "MyPositionMarker" with your picture
3. Add some markers

Documentations:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

EDIT: it can be easily to just calculate the offset of the markers with the user and not using a map, isn't it?

EDIT2:

```
    mMap = getMap();
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
    mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mProvider));
```

Where mProvider is a custom tiles provider.

Comment: I want to start from the map, so, immagine there's a map, but it's invisible. The problem is: I don't know how to hide a map and setting a image instead.

Comment: Thanks Kevinrob, it's not exactly what I was looking for. In that way I hided the map but the grid was still there and I can't set a "Tile" with all the properties of the ImageView, for example, but thanks anyway :)